# Dynamic image resource on foreground notification not working properly

Tags: java, android, notifications

Android foreground notification was working properly before i replaced

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img1)
```

with dynamic image resource

```
int dynamicImageResource = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
.setSmallIcon(dynamicImageResource)
```

where i is a variable. The problem is, it issues a notification stating that:

**Touch for more information or to stop the app.** instead of actual notification.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too quick to question. Actually i variable was set to 0 for which there was no image img0 on the drawable folder which leads to the notification stating **Touch for more information or to stop the app.** .

Conclusion: **Touch for more information or to stop the app.** notification is issued if .setSmallIcon is not set on the notification.